# Is it possible to suppress "skipping" behavior between wget tries?

Tags: windows, wget

I'm using wget to download a set of files via HTTP, using one wget call per URL, in a simple cmd.exe batch.

Also, I alternate between mirrors randomly and want to keep separate tree for each mirror, like:

```
http://server06//files/file1.txt  -> temp\server06\files\file1.txt
http://server03//files/file65.txt -> temp\server03\files\file65.txt
```

What I do now is:

```
echo !url! | .\runners\wget.exe --tries=3 --force-directories --directory-prefix=.\temp\ --input-file=-
```

Sometimes it happens that, for some reason, server closes TCP connection.  I'm using `--tries=3` to work around this.  In such case, default behavior of wget is, that it would skip the bytes that it already downloaded, and continue from that point, something like this:

```
2011-07-19 13:24:52 (68.1 KB/s) - Connection closed at byte 65396. Retrying.

--2011-07-19 13:24:54--  (try: 3) 
http://server06//files/filex.txt
Connecting to server|10.10.0.108|:80... failed: Unknown error.
Resolving server... 10.10.0.108
Connecting to server|10.10.0.108|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 206 Partial Content
Length: 166400 (163K), 101004 (99K) remaining [text/plain]
Saving to:
`./temp/server06/files/filex.txt'

        [ skipping 50K ]
    50K ,,,,,,,,,, ,,,....... .......... .......... .......... 61% 2.65M 0s
   100K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 92% 1.62M 0s
   150K .......... ..                                         100% 1.64M=0.06s

utime(./temp/server06/files/filex.txt):
Permission denied
2011-07-19 13:25:15 (1.72 MB/s) -
`./temp/server06/files/filex.txt'
saved [166400/166400]
```

My problem is that I don't want wget to download the file in two parts. I want wget to try more times, but if any attempt fails for any reason, I want it to start over (even at the cost of not downloading the file at all!).

The background is that I'm testing a code in a filter driver that will be covered only if the file is downloaded at one piece.  And my tests fail because of this behavior.

Question is: is it possible to suppress this behavior?  I.e. make wget try as much as is configured by a parameter, while either downloading complete file or zero bytes within each attempt?

Or I should look for another workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure you will be happier with  [**the libcurl library**](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/). It takes just one call per url and libcurl does all the rest of the work. On top of that, there's first-rate support for the package.

The particular case you're having trouble with won't be a problem using libcurl.

HTH

Comment: Well, I thought about cURL, but I did not find out how curl.exe would my files the same way as wget does.  I alternate mirrors randomly a nd I want to keep them separately. (I'm going to edit my post to reflect this.)

Comment: Not cURL, but libcurl, which is a library that has functions you can call (cURL uses this library, by the way). To use it you have to write a small program, but there are *many* demo programs on the libcurl site that you can adapt for your use.

Comment: Okay, it seems I won't be able to avoid a little bit of programming. Thanks, Pete!